# Lua: table element doesn't want to be copied while the value exists

Tags: lua, lua-table

The key I'm assigning value to still remains nil after return!

```
p = {};
for i = 0, 1000 do
    p[ i ] = {};
end

t = {}
t.__index = t

function new()
    local o = setmetatable({}, t)


    for key, value in pairs( p[1] ) do
        print(key .. " : " .. value)
        o[ key ] = value
    end

    t.__newindex = function(t, key, value)
        if type(value) ~= "function" then
          p[1][key] = value
        end
    end


    return o
end

local something = new()

something.xxx = 666
print(p[1].xxx)

local something = new()
print(something.xxx)
print(p[1].xxx)
```

The problem is with it:

```
for key, value in pairs( p[1] ) do
    print(key .. " : " .. value)
    o[ key ] = value
end
```

It shows xxx : 666 but o[ key ] still remains nil when I return it. The output is

```
666
xxx : 666
nil
666
```

EDIT: yeah, I realized just now. I'll give you upvotes later because of net bandwidth(cant run stac with javascript) Thanks, now it works. Created new object based on previous one.

Comment: Why are you setting `t.__newindex` on every invocation of new?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`o[ key ] = value` will invoke the `newindex` metamethod. But since you *haven't set it* yet, it will do the default action. Which is setting the `value` into `o`'s table at the index `key`.

Of course, the `index` metamethod won't care about what is in `o`'s table; it's looking at itself. So your later `o[key]` will look in the metatable for the `key`, which it won't find.

It's unclear what this code is trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You set the `__index` metamethod for the new table `o` to t, which contains only `__index` and `__newindex`, none of which equal `xxx`, so the lookup fails and returns `nil`. You probably wanted to say `t.__index = p` instead.